# (c++) Declaring a class member in a class

Tags: c++, class, declare

I am trying to create a CBuffer member in every CClient class like this :

```
#ifndef CCLI_INC
#define CCLI_INC
#include "CBuffer.h"
#include "main.h"

    class CClient
    {
    private:

        CBuffer *m_buffer;


    public:
        CClient();



    };
```

but this code gives me

```
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Although I have included cbuffer.h header, it gives this weird error..

Comment: What's in CBuffer.h? You will get this error if CBuffer is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declare `CBuffer` and lose the `include`.

```
#ifndef CCLI_INC
#define CCLI_INC
#include "main.h"
class CBuffer;
class CClient
{
private:

    CBuffer *m_buffer;
public:
    CClient();
};
```

Comment: yeah thanks it didn't give any errors. can you please explain why should i re-define class ?

Comment: @deniz you're not re-defining the class, only declaring it. When you only use it as a pointer, or parameter, or return type, you don't need a full definition, but only to tell the compiler that a class with that name exists. And forward declarations should be prefered to inclusions when possible.

Comment: should i declare it on each file i will use ?
by the way main.h includes all of the header files with #pragma once.

Comment: @deniz if you can, yes. Always prefer forward-declaration instead of an include. Refer to this answer for reasons why you should do so - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906402/should-one-use-forward-declarations-instead-of-includes-wherever-possible/9906429#9906429