# error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found - global function

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

I have this:

**`a.h`**:

```
class a
{
}
void func(){} //some golobal function
```

**`b.h`**:

```
include "a.h"
class b : public a
{
}
```

**`b.cpp`**:

```
#include "b.h"
```

I get the error:

```
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I think I get the error because global function defined twice. I try to put `extern` before the function but is doesnt work. I use also `#ifndef..` and I still get error. How can solve this problem?

Comment: Compiler lists the symbols which are multiply defined. What are those symbols?

Comment: If the definition of `func` is included twice in b.cpp file, compiler would have given an error while compiling the file.

Comment: possible duplicate [Should one use forward declarations instead of includes wherever possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906402/should-one-use-forward-declarations-instead-of-includes-wherever-possible)

Comment: Are there multiple compilation units (cpp files)?

Answer (score 3):

You have either only to declare the function in header a.h and define it in some cpp module or define it as an inline function. For example

```
inline void func(){}
```

Otherwise the function will be defined as many times as there are cpp modules that include either header a.h or b.h.

Comment: I still cannot deduce why this would solve a problem. Any way, a.h is included once and only in one compilation unit.

Comment: @dbasic And what about the module that contains function main? Does it include either a.h or b.h?

Comment: This program may or may not contain main depending whether it is application or some library. It must be mentioned in the question.

Comment: @dbasic if the linker issued the error it means that at least two modules contain the function definition.

Comment: You are right. But whole error message is missing from the question. It might be some other symbols as well. Compiler also says about the symbols which are duplicate.