# Defining const in implementation file

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

Foo.h:

```
include "Bar.h"

class Bar;

class Foo {
   const Bar mBar;

public:
   Foo(const Bar &bar);
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo(const Bar &bar) : mBar(bar) {}
```

I receive the following compilation error:

> 'Foo::mBar' uses undefined class 'Bar'

Is const definition not allowed in implementation file?

Obviously in this case I could move ctor implementation into header file.

But What is an alternative if I want to call Bar ctor which may take arguments requiring forward declaration instead of copy ctor and still keep Bar member variable constant?
So for example:

Foo.h:

```
include "Bar.h"

class Bar;
class BaraParams;

class Foo {
   const Bar mBar;

public:
   Foo(const BarParams &barParams);
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo(const BarParams &barParams) : mBar(barParams) {} //call bar ctor
```

Bar.h:

```
include "BarParams.h"

class Bar{
public:
   Bar(const BarParams &barParams);
};
```

Or am I not doing this right? I don't even know if this is a good idea.

Comment: The compilation error has nothing to do with the `const` qualifier. As `mBar` is neither a reference, nor a pointer to a `Bar`, the compiler needs to know the size of a `Bar`, which requires `Bar` to be defined once the compiler encounters the `mBar` member variable.

Comment: hmm so I can use a reference or pointer only?

Comment: No, you can also use a plain `Bar` if you just define `Bar` before `Foo`. The definition of class members is usually done in header files, so that the `#include` preprocessor directive for the corresponding header file of the `Bar` class is sufficient if you organized your source code correctly.

Comment: ahh so it could be order of declarations? in my real code, which is too big to paste here I use stdafx.h to keep all includes. And include stdafx.h instead.. perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: If you `#include "stdafx.h"` in `Foo.h`, then you have to `#include "Bar.h"` before `#include "Foo.h"` in the `stdafx.h` file and add include guards to your header files if you didn't do that already. So yes, it's most likely a problem in the order of declaration.

Comment: If you use references or pointers don't include the header files where these classes are defined but use forward declarations. As explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The header file has to include the Bar header file.
The full thing is like this :

```
include "Bar.h"

class Foo {
   const Bar mBar; 
   //because it is Bar and not Bar& or Bar* forward declarations are not possible

public:
   Foo(const Bar &bar);
};
```

You can and should use forward declarations in following situation

```
class Foo {
   const Bar& mBar; 

public:
   Foo(const Bar &bar);
};
```

but then the Bar include has to be present in the implementation file.
The same reasoning can be applied here instead of this :

```
include "BarParams.h"

class Bar{
public:
   Bar(const BarParams &barParams);
};
```

do this :

```
class BarParams;

class Bar{
public:
   Bar(const BarParams &barParams);
};
```

Doing that avoids unneeded includes all over your header files, and makes the life of your compiler a lot easier. In large projects the compilation times can be reduced significantly.

Comment: well in my real code, which is too big to paste here I use stdafx.h to keep all includes. And include stdafx.h instead.. perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: I am getting a bunch of incomplete type errors now if I want to do anything with BarParams besides reference them.

Comment: the include is needed in the implementation file. Also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906402/should-one-use-forward-declarations-instead-of-includes-wherever-possible